# InitBinder for Spring Rest controller for @Valid

Tags: spring, validation, rest

The way to use a Validator interface for Spring @RestController based is to create a validator custom class, implement Validator interface. In the controller class call InitBinder to register the validator class. Then when the REST req comes, the validator for that class is called. This still has a problem for me. Say I have a PersonValidator class that does one type of validation for POST and another type for PUT. Since both these handlers exist in the same REST controller class, how can I run different validations?
Say in the same rest controller class, i want to use PostPersonValidator for POST and PutPersonValidator for PUT. I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this article: http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/02/12/spring-mvc-custom-validator-example/

You basically have to create two separate validators - just as you said (one for POST, one for PUT). Then just call them inside your proper POST/PUT handling methods. Should be pretty straightforward if you follow the linked example.

Comment: Thanks but I doubt that it is the correct way. In case of rest APIs, why do I have to use ModelAndView annotation? Today my RestController does not need it. If I am doing Validation, technically @Valid and InitBinder are enough to do it but not at controller level. I hope you get my doubt now?